# Handling null with dataset and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method which uses LINQ to look up a company in a local `DataSet`, using a company id (`Guid`). The properties from the data set is then stored in a class (`CompanyModel`), which is created for the occasion. One of the properties is the `OrganizationNo`, which is of type `Long` in the DataSet, but `String` in the `CompanyModel`.

The issue is, `OrganizationNo` can be `null` in the DataSet. This causes the `ToString()` method to throw an exception. I can tried fixing it (see below), but with no luck.

Isn't there some sort of simple, easy to read solution for this, which does not require multiple lines of code and/or use of try/catch?

**UPDATE**

The exception is thrown at an earlier point, since `query` becomes `null` if the organization number is `null`. Hence it has nothing to do with `ToString()` failing. The code never gets that far. I have tried changing the `NullValue` property of the `OrganizationNo` in the data table from `(Throw Exception)` to `(Null)`, but this is not allowed. Is it a bad design we have chosen, using `Long` for a property which is sometimes null?

```
public void SelectCompany(Guid companyId)
{
    SelectedCompany = new CompanyModel();
    SelectedCompany.Id = companyId;

    CompanyDataTabel dt = DataSet.Company;

    // Look up the company in the company table in the data Set
    var query = from company in dt.AsEnumerable()
                where company.Id == companyId
                select new
                {
                   company.OrganizationNo,
                   company.Name,
                   company.PhoneNo,
                   company.Email,
                };

    // If the OrganizationNo is null, then the entire query is null. 
    // Hence the '.Count()' method will fail.
    if (query.Count() != 1)
    {
        // One (and only one) company should match the organisation ID. 
        throw new ArgumentException("Multiple companies found.");
    }

    // These properties are never null and causes no issues
    SelectedCompany.Name = query.First().Name;
    SelectedCompany.PhoneNumber = query.First().PhoneNo;
    SelectedCompany.EmailAddress = query.First().Email;
    SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = query.First().OrganizationNo.ToString()

}
```

Comment: Please update your post to show the full stack trace of the exception thrown?

Comment: `?.` used for `Nullable<T>` with `T` = value types, not the value types itself. So it works for `long?` but not for `long`.

Comment: The problem actually occurs earlier. It seems to be caused by `OrganizationNo` not being allowed to be of value `null`. This cases the entire `query` to be null, if the `OrganizationNo` is. I will update my question.

Comment: Instead of `if (query.Count() != 1)` you should use `var org = query.Single();`. This handles the case that there is none or more than one and will throw this exception on both cases. It's more efficient because you only need to execute the query once. Btw, all your `query.First()` calls must execute the whole query again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks four you input. I am still new to C# and indeed LINQ. Hence the sub-optimal code. But that still doesn't change the fact, that I will never be able to look up a company where `OrganizationNo` is `null`, since the query then becomes `null`.

Comment: @Noceo: no, the query is not null but you get an exception if you execute the query because it accesses a property that is null which throws an error if set to Throw Exception. Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query is that you are using a strongly typed `DataSet` which throws an error if you try to access a property that is `null`. To handle that case the `DataSet` automatically adds a `bool` method that you have to check before you access that nullable-column property. But your query creates an anonymous type that accesses this nullable property without this check. For that reason you will get the exception when the query is executed which is at `query.First()`.

Use this query instead:

```
var query = from company in dt.AsEnumerable()
            where company.Id == companyId
            select new
            {
               OrganizationNo = company.IsOrganizationNoNull()
                                ? string.Empty 
                                : company.OrganizationNo.ToString(),
               company.Name,
               company.PhoneNo,
               company.Email,
            };
```

---

Side-note:

Instead of `if (query.Count() != 1)` you should use `Single`:

```
var company = query.Single(); // throws a desired exception if there are no or more than two records
SelectedCompany.Name = company.Name;
SelectedCompany.PhoneNumber = company.PhoneNo;
SelectedCompany.EmailAddress = company.Email;
SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = company.OrganizationNo;
```

This handles the case that there is none or more than one and will throw this exception on both cases. It's more efficient because you only need to execute the query once. Btw, all your `query.First()` calls must execute the whole query again

Comment: I get a compile time error when I try to implement the `.IsOrganizationNoNull`: "Cannot convert method group 'IsOrgnizationNoNull' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?"

Comment: I'll be damned, it works now. Thank you :-). I have made some edits in your code, since it had some minor errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can check `OrganisationNumber` property is must be define `Nulable`.. `Nulable<long>` or `long?` like this `public long? OrganisationNumber {get;set;}`

```
SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = string.Empty;

if(query.First() != null && query.First().OrganizationNo.HasValue)
{
   SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = 
    query.First().OrganizationNo.Value.ToString();
}
```

or

```
SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = query.First() != null && query.First().OrganizationNo.HasValue ?  "" : "";
```

or

```
SelectedCompany.OrganisationNumber = 
query.First() != null ? query.First().OrganizationNo?.ToString() ?? string.Empty : string.Empty;
```

Comment: The column `OrganizationNo` in the data table has the property `NullValue: (Throw exception)`. It also has `DefaultValue: <DBNull>`. This might be part of the explanation, but I am not quite sure what to make of it?

Comment: did you set DataTable column AllowDBNull = true;

Comment: The property `AllowDBNull` is set to `true` but that doesn't seem to matter. The entire query becomes `null` when `OrganizationNo` is `null` (see update of original post).

Answer (score 0):

long type variable itself can not be null. but `Nullable<long>` can

Answer (score 0):

The `?.` operator works with `null`, which works for reference types or nullable value types, but not for `normal` value types like `long`.